# Authenticate by one of multiple email addresses per user

Tags: laravel

A user can have multiple emails. I got two tables "users" and "user_emails". Registration is working fine and it writes the email to user_emails.
Later the users shell be able to add more email-adresses within a backend gui. Now i am stuck with the verification at login, as a user should be able to use any of the email adresses out of "user_emails" with the passwort out of "users".
What do i have to do to get this working?
Thank you.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Are you using the default Laravel login controller or did you roll your own?

Comment: It is the latest version 5.7. It is based upon the regular make:auth, so i only added a "create" function to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController. Everything else is left unchanged - so the login controller is.